# React Countdown Clock not sure if issue is with my setInterval or my setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, setstate

I've been working on FreeCodeCamp Front End development project 25 + 5 Clock. I'm trying to click the play button and make it countdown. I know it enters my countdown function but when logging it, I think it is only calling once. So I think my setInterval might be wrong but I've also struggled with using setState on all projects. They have only taught using this.setState and this has often caused problems because the state is not what I expect it to be (like it's not immediate). I'm not ready to dive into the concepts of DidMount, WillMount, etc so I'd like to stay in the boundaries of using setState if that is where my problem is. Below is a link to my codepen

[25 + 5 Clock Codepen](https://codepen.io/RawleJuglal/pen/GRQrYjW)

```
handleCountDown(pause){
let timer;
if(pause){
  clearInterveral(timer)
} else {
  if(this.state.minutesLeft === '' && this.state.secondsLeft === ''){
    if(this.state.session){
        timer =  setInterval(this.countdown(Number(this.state.sessionLength), 0), 1000)
    } else {
      timer =  setInterval(this.countdown(Number(this.state.breakLength), 0), 1000)
    }
  } else {
    timer =  setInterval(this.countdown(Number(this.state.minutesLeft), Number(this.state.secondsLeft)), 1000)
  }   
}}

countdown(min, sec){
const second = 1000;
const minutes = second * 60;

const countDate = (new Date().getTime()) + (second * sec) + (minutes * min);//target time
const now = new Date().getTime();
const gap = countDate - now;



const textMinute = Math.floor(gap / minutes);
const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minutes)/ second);

if(textSecond === 0){
  textSecond = '00'
}
this.setState({
  minutesLeft:textMinute.toString(),
  secondsLeft:textSecond.toString()
})}
```

Comment: You have lot of mistakes in code, starting with few, once you correct those, you can figure out the actual root cause --- 1) setInterval takes function or callback as first parameter. You can't pass the method invocation directly. Change the code to `setInterval(() => this.countdown(Number(this.state.breakLength), 0), 1000)`. 2) The right method name to clear the interval is `clearInterval` instead of `clearInterveral`. 3) You need to persist the timer, you can define that in state.

Comment: 4) While calculating the date you are doing `const countDate = (new Date().getTime()) ` which is initializing with new time everytime instead of   finding the diff from previous elapsed time.